# In LSTM texts, sometimes the current input and previous hidden state are concatenated, then multiplied by a weight. Sometimes, the other way. Why?

Tags: neural-networks, matrix, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

In the first case, the input and previous hidden state are concatenated then multiplied by a weight matrix, resulting in four matrix multiplications.
e.g. https://bond-kirill-alexandrovich.medium.com/lstm-in-details-is-easy-501630afbcb9

In other cases, the input and previous hidden state are multiplied by weights, then added together, resulting in eight matrix multiplications (four for input, four for previous hidden state).
e.g. https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/optimizing-recurrent-neural-networks-cudnn-5/

Why? Are there any tradeoffs between the two approaches?